# Getting data for nested components in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

According to the documentation, fetching data through `getStaticProps` can only be called from pages, not from components which are located under `/components` directory or a child / nested components. In situations as such, where data needs to be fetched via components, it seems that you can either:

1. Fetch data by using useEffect
2. Fetch data from parents components (a components that exists under `/pages`) and send the data to the child / nested component.

Are these two methods are the officially supported methods (recommended way to do it)? Or are there any other alternative ways in fetching data for child / nested components?

Comment: Those are the two supported methods for data fetching.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I guess I would have to stick to those two methods.